# Deployed Firebase function V2 callable returns 404

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I set the region for functions in APP initially

```
const functions = getFunctions(app, 'us-west1')
```

Then using the following to invoke it.

```
const cleantext = httpsCallable(functions, 'cleantext')
```

Using the local emulator with a callable V2 function with following URL is called from the App and it works as expected:

```
http://localhost:5001/project-name/us-west1/cleantext
```

The issue is once deployed the function is never even triggered from the call in the App(checked the logs)

**Issue**:  after deploying the function the following URL is invoked from the app which results in 404 error

```
https://us-west1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/cleantext
```

I have checked the logs of the functions , and its not being triggered at all with the URL

I feel as if the Url being called of the deployed function is wrong.

The firebase console shows the function as Http Request for some reason as well.

[image: firebase console function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Until Cloud Functions (2nd gen) supports cloudfunctions.net URLs, you will have to use a different initializer in your client code. Rather than providing a function name, provide a full URL to the client SDK. The URL for your function is printed at the end of a successful firebase deploy command:

Thus,

I had to invoke using the deployed random url with `httpsCallableFromURL` function on the client and it worked